# Does More Layering will do the Job?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection

Consider there is a very complex business requirement, that need several business logic steps to be executed when an operation is initiated. For example, when user submit a request then the steps needed to be executed is:

- Validate the data

  - Validate if request already exists
  - Validate if user is exists
  - Validate if user has sufficient financial amount to submit the request
  - Validate if user can immediaetly publish the request
  - Validate if there is item for the request
  - Validate if the item for the request is valid
  - Validate the item to have no negative amount
  - ... (further validation)
- Store the data to repository
- Send e-mail to user or appropriate party
- ... (maybe another steps to be done)

The example above may be far from a real business requirement, but considering it is, then what I imagine is that there will around 10+ services for this operation.

When using constructor dependency, it should be a bad thing to have 10+ constructors, so I think refactoring it will do the job. Some illustration of the refactored design:

```
ISubmitter(IValidator, IRequestRepository, INotification)
IValidator(IRequestValidator, IItemValidator)
IRequestValidator(IRequestRepository, IUserValidator, IItemExistValidator)
IUserValidator(IUserRepository, IUserFinancialValidator, IUserPublisherValidator)
IItemValidator(IItemRepository, IItemAmountValidator)
... // maybe more
```

The item amount validation process has made 4 layers from the submitter: ISubmitter->IValidator->IItemValidator->ItemAmountValidator.

I know that in terms of Separation of Concern, I can easily get the correct implementation in which I need (example: ItemAmountValidation). But in terms of debugging code, won't it make harder to track which validation class it use? Since the constructor injection is defined in implementation and not in the interface?

Consider the worst scenario, when the debugger is not the developer, there is only a minimum test scenario and there is no documentation at all.

Comment: Interesting: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/02/09/IsLayeringWorththeMapping/

Comment: @Steven Yes, I have read the article too. But it is talking about how entity pass between layer, and I ask about layering/partitioning the business logic. Nice article that must be read though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But in terms of debugging code, won't it make harder to track which
>   validation class it use? Since the constructor injection is defined in
>   implementation and not in the interface?

Yes, it probably would make you have to jump through more classes when debugging. However, this kind of design allows your code to be tested (using TDD of course) and when practicing TDD, you will have to debug your code much less then before.

Comment: Actually I like your answer. It realized me that DI rely heavily on unit tests to make sure that each component work well, and will work well when integrated, so I will need to debug less. Thanks for emphasized it.

Answer (score 2):

The logic you are talking about belongs to different layers, but need to be injected into your application layer. What I would do is inject the components needed to do the tasks, like a command handler that executes the request; a validator that takes care of validating input, a repository that will handle data logic, and a Mailer component (or service) that will send the mail.

It's all about putting the responsibilities in the correct component. Constructor injection is an excellent choice that give you a lot of advantages concerning flexibility, testability and it makes your code understandable.

As far as debugging goes, I don't think the little more effort you have to do should be a reason to not structure your code in a modular way. Just set the correct breakpoints and it's fine.

Maybe http://tinyurl.com/d99w8rl can give you some more insight.

Comment: Even different layers, it consist mostly in service layer. I just can't imagine more complex operation where need more services, or I can give it all service-layer example.

Comment: Take that aside, I have read a portion (yeah, it's a long article) of the link and it is good. However I don't prefer 2 things from it. One is the generic repository interface, maybe I just don't know what to use it and it seems complex. Another one is the use of Service Locator (ObjectFactory.GetObject(Type t)). It's subjective though. +1 btw...

Comment: ObjectFactory is only used once in the attribute, I believe, because there is no other way. The rest uses constructor injection. The generic repository is in fact not that complex once you have it, because it saves you from writing repetitive code.

Comment: Yes, maybe I just not quite used to repository pattern yet that I don't know the use of it. For object factory, why don't you just inject the handler? Or inject the factory? Imho, static method is hard to test, unable to mock and creating dependency.

Comment: Object factory in the attribute cannot be injected because it's an attribute, it needs a default constructor. So there's no way to inject anything :(

Comment: Maybe I need to learn it more, it's new to me. (And in fact, another downside of the architecture is it hard to learn by standard programmer (smile) )

Comment: Yes, of course, if you know how to drive a car it doesn't mean you know how to design one :-) (but you can learn it, of course)

Comment: I have read the articles and understand the concept. Sadly, I just don't like the design. It has many IOC inside. I have created an IOC framework before and only me that know how it works. And IOC create a dependency to StructureMap. I like the validation technique though, it is well structured and easy to implement. Maybe I will use it someday. It is indeed a well structured framework but I just don't like it. :)

Comment: Can you explain to me what is wrong to have a dependency on StructureMap? You also have a dependency on .NET, Entity Framework, nLog or any other framework you may be using. If you consider this to be a dependency, well, then don't use any framework at all. I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. You can easily replace StructureMap by another IoC container, as the only dependency is at startup (bootstrapper). All the rest of the code does not have one single dependency on StructureMap, it's using constructor injection. That's the whole idea, to be independent.

Comment: I am working with legacy code, in a tight-policies company. It is not easy to use a component such as StructureMap. Yes, I also not yet used nLog and Entity Framework, just .Net. Currently I just used Poor Man's, but even someday I will use StructureMap, it will be only on the starting point. I'm not against StructureMap, I just don't like the static call. I also don't like IOC, because someday the code will be passed to someone else. I aren't against it, just don't like it.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to see some valid arguments against IoC. (not taking into account your legacy code, assume it's not there, I understand you are in a company where change is not easy)

Comment: Sorry to confuse, I mistaken the term IOC wrong. What I really mean is Service Locator (IOC Container). Why I don't like it: if the module using IOC or if something between the request and respond (with service locator inside) need to be modified, only me (the creator) can understand the flow. Furthermore, it can be abused by new programmer who don't understand the risk of using Service Locator.

Comment: Of course, service locator is an anti pattern and should only be used if there is NO other way. But this is, like I said, only used once in that global exception handler attribute, because there is no other way. Instead of using ObjectFactory you could just create a new GlobalExceptionHandler instance yourself like 'new GlobalExceptionHandler().

Comment: Alternatively you can just use Setter Injection in the case of the GlobalExceptionHandler attribute. So then you don't use ObjectFactory at all.

Comment: Yes, I agree. This is interesting discussion. I have blogged my thoughts at http://serlock-works.blogspot.com/2013/04/not-all-architecture-is-fit-for-your.html.